# Input Automatically With Javascript yii2

Tags: javascript, php, yii2

In my case, I want to calculate total, but I want to make automatically calculate.
Total is addition from quantity and price previous, I get the result and success, but now I don't know where is my mistake
What can I do so my total is automatically calculate?
This is my view:

```html
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use yii\web\View;
use yii\widgets\MaskedInput;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model backend\models\Dsc */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
?>

<div class="dsc-form">
    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'qty')->textInput() ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'unit_price')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'item_no')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'total_price')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
</div>

<?php
    $this->RegisterJs ( "
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#pengeluaran-price').keyup(function(){
            <!-- Ambil nilai bayar dan diskon !-->
            var bayar=parseInt($('#pengeluaran-quantity').val());
            var diskon=parseInt($('#pengeluaran-price').val());

            <!-- Perhitungan bayar-(diskon/100 x bayar) !-->
            var total_bayar= diskon * bayar;
            $('#pengeluaran-total').val(total_bayar);
        });
    });
", View::POS_END);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be there is problem of selector,

Replace u'r code

```
<?php
    $this->RegisterJs ( "
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#pengeluaran-unit_price').keyup(function(){
            <!-- Ambil nilai bayar dan diskon !-->
            var bayar=parseInt($('#pengeluaran-qty').val());
            var diskon=parseInt($('#pengeluaran-unit_price').val());

            <!-- Perhitungan bayar-(diskon/100 x bayar) !-->
            var total_bayar= diskon * bayar;
            $('#pengeluaran-total_price').val(total_bayar);
        });
    });
", View::POS_END);
?>
```